# How do I obtain the ASCII code of a character?

Tags: qt

I have a `char` variable, declared for example as:

```
char a = 's';
```

How can I get the ASCII code of this symbol?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` holds the ascii value of `'s'` (115). Think of a char as just a small integer. If you want it in an integer for whatever reason, just cast it.

```
char a = 's';
int code = a; //or (int)a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use QChar? :) http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qchar.html